# Capturar datos en una fila de excel y guardarlo automáticamente en mysql

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, msql

Muy buenas, quisiera saber si existe algún método para insertar o capturar datos de excel y guardarlo en la DB mysql automáticamente, tengo los datos desde la pagina web con una tabla, lo he intentado con mysql for excel pero no lo guarda automáticamente, gracias de antemano!

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Con VBA podrías desarrollar una macro que se conecte a tu base SQL y hacer un INSERT INTO y guardarlo

Comment: Muchas gracias! he estado investigando el VBA y he desarrollado una macro que me resulto útil, Gracias de nuevo y Saludos!